# What is the meaning of the regressor characteristic root?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, multicollinearity, eigenvalues, condition-number

As described by Greene's Econometric Analysis (7th Edition), the regressor matrix's condition number measures how singular the matrix is. Therefore, the condition number is a measure of multicollinearity.

[image]

Yet, I came across a regression matrix with large condition number (724047.5108990307), but low correlation among its components, resulting in the following correlation matrix:

[image]

Thus, I would like to understand the condition number in more detail. What is the interpretation of the characteristic roots of the regressor matrix and why does a large condition number mean the matrix is singular?

Comment: The condition number of your matrix is 1.0094, not 724048.  What's going on?  A typographical error somewhere?  Answers to your general questions about condition numbers can be found by [searching our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22condition%20number%22).

Comment: I computed it in Python: numpy.linalg.cond(matrix, p=None)

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was the correlation matrix, not the regressor matrix

Comment: Does `numpy.linalg.cond` first center the columns of `matrix`?  I suspect it does not, in which case there's not much a relationship between the two condition numbers.